# How do I do a F-test in python

Tags: python, statistics

How do I do an F-test to check if the variance is equivalent in two vectors in Python?

For example if I have

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [1,3,-1,2,1,5,-1,6,-1,2]
```

is there something similar to

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a, b)
```

I found

```
sp.stats.f(a, b)
```

But it appears to be something different to an F-test

Comment: If you just want to test for equal variance, scipy has [Bartlett](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bartlett.html) and [Levene](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levene.html) tests.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The test statistic F test for equal variances is simply:

```
F = Var(X) / Var(Y)
```

Where `F` is distributed as `df1 = len(X) - 1, df2 = len(Y) - 1`

[`scipy.stats.f`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html) which you mentioned in your question has a CDF method. This means you can generate a p-value for the given statistic and test whether that p-value is greater than your chosen alpha level.

Thus:

```
alpha = 0.05 #Or whatever you want your alpha to be.
p_value = 1 - scipy.stats.f.cdf(F, df1, df2)
```

Alternatively, the p-value can be calculated using the sf-method of the f-test:

```
p_value = scipy.stats.f.sf(F, df1, df2)
if p_value > alpha:
    # Reject the null hypothesis that Var(X) == Var(Y)
```

Note that the F-test is extremely sensitive to non-normality of X and Y, so you're probably better off doing a more robust test such as [Levene's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) or [Bartlett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) unless you're reasonably sure that X and Y are distributed normally. These tests can be found in the `scipy` api:

- [Bartlett's test](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bartlett.html)
- [Levene's test](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levene.html)

Comment: This answer is mathematically correct but conceptually wrong. The p_value is rather `1 - CDF`. This is the area under the probability distribution above your F_critical.

I would write it this way:
`p_value = scipy.stats.f.sf(F, df1, df2)`

  I think the survival function calculates this slightly different so you want to double check in case you are handling very small p_values (due to multiple comparisons)

Then you reject the null hypothesis if `p_value < alpha`

Comment: Are the variances not significantly different if the p-value is less than 0.05 OR greater than 0.95? If F = 0.25, i.e. the variance of Y is 4 times greater than the variance of X, (with say df1 = df2 = 10), then p = 0.98 based on 1 - CDF. So, I would go for less than 0.05 OR greater than 0.95 to test for significantly different variances.

Comment: I would personally advised against using Bartlett's test for non-normal data as the statistic is is not reliable with "moderate" departures from normality. Better off with Levene's.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who came here searching for an ANOVA F-test or to compare between models for feature selection

- [`sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif) does ANOVA tests, and
- [`sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression) does sequential testing of regressions

Answer (score 10):

To do a one way anova you can use

```
import scipy.stats as stats

stats.f_oneway(a,b)
```

One way Anova checks if the variance between the groups is greater then the variance within groups, and computes the probability of observing this variance ratio using F-distribution. A good tutorial can be found here:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/anova/v/anova-1-calculating-sst-total-sum-of-squares

Comment: I _assume_ the OP asked about comparing the variances of two samples, for which **the test statistic is the ratio of the sample variances**. If you run ANOVA on two groups, the omnibus F test statistic value will be the **ratio of the between-group variance vs within-group variance**, which is not the same thing. Try it! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple function to calculate the one-sided or two-sided F test with Python and SciPy. The results have been checked against the output of the `var.test()` function in R. Please keep in mind the warnings mentioned in the other answers concerning the sensitivity of the F-test to non-normality.

```
import scipy.stats as st

def f_test(x, y, alt="two_sided"):
    """
    Calculates the F-test.
    :param x: The first group of data
    :param y: The second group of data
    :param alt: The alternative hypothesis, one of "two_sided" (default), "greater" or "less"
    :return: a tuple with the F statistic value and the p-value.
    """
    df1 = len(x) - 1
    df2 = len(y) - 1
    f = x.var() / y.var()
    if alt == "greater":
        p = 1.0 - st.f.cdf(f, df1, df2)
    elif alt == "less":
        p = st.f.cdf(f, df1, df2)
    else:
        # two-sided by default
        # Crawley, the R book, p.355
        p = 2.0*(1.0 - st.f.cdf(f, df1, df2))
    return f, p
```

Comment: In standard statistical practice, ddof=1 provides an unbiased estimator of the variance of a hypothetical infinite population. ddof=0 provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for normally distributed variables.

Comment: @JustDoIt Thanks but my goal with this Python function was to reproduce _exactly_ the output of the `var.test()` function in R. Hence I'd rather not mess with the `ddof` settings.

Answer (score 4):

if you need a two-tailed test, you can proceed as follow, i choosed alpha =0.05:

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [1,3,-1,2,1,5,-1,6,-1,2]
print('Variance a={0:.3f}, Variance b={1:.3f}'.format(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1)))
fstatistics = np.var(a, ddof=1)/np.var(b, ddof=1) # because we estimate mean from data
fdistribution = stats.f(len(a)-1,len(b)-1) # build an F-distribution object
p_value = 2*min(fdistribution.cdf(f_critical), 1-fdistribution.cdf(f_critical))
f_critical1 = fdistribution.ppf(0.025)
f_critical2 = fdistribution.ppf(0.975)
print(fstatistics,f_critical1, f_critical2 )
if (p_value<0.05):
    print('Reject H0', p_value)
else:
    print('Cant Reject H0', p_value)
```

if you want to proceed to an ANOVA like test where only large values can cause rejection, you can proceed to right-tail test, you need to pay attention to the order of variances (fstatistics = var1/var2 or var2/var1):

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [1,3,-1,2,1,5,-1,6,-1,2]
print('Variance a={0:.3f}, Variance b={1:.3f}'.format(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1)))
fstatistics = max(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1))/min(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1)) # because we estimate mean from data
fdistribution = stats.f(len(a)-1,len(b)-1) # build an F-distribution object 
p_value = 1-fdistribution.cdf(fstatistics)
f_critical = fd.ppf(0.95)
print(fstatistics, f_critical)
if (p_value<0.05):
    print('Reject H0', p_value)
else:
    print('Cant Reject H0', p_value)
```

The left-tailed can be done as follow :

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
b = [1,3,-1,2,1,5,-1,6,-1,2]
print('Variance a={0:.3f}, Variance b={1:.3f}'.format(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1)))
fstatistics = min(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1))/max(np.var(a, ddof=1), np.var(b, ddof=1)) # because we estimate mean from data
fdistribution = stats.f(len(a)-1,len(b)-1) # build an F-distribution object
p_value = fdistribution.cdf(fstatistics)
f_critical = fd.ppf(0.05)
print(fstatistics, f_critical)
if (p_value<0.05):
    print('Reject H0', p_value)
else:
    print('Cant Reject H0', p_value)
```